# curl: get text generated by js

Tags: php, curl

I created this function to fetch the contents of a url with curl

```
function leggiUrl($url){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}
```

if I enter a URL whose content is partly generated by a script JavaScript, this text is taken from the function.
I would like to grab the text (finished) of any page.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to perform your own analysis on what happens when the page is loaded and from where it grabs all the content. I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. cURL retrieves the HTML page but doesn't parse it